# Algorithm for counting meal weight

Tags: algorithm

i am making an app for counting a meal weight.

I have a database with material and its nutritional values:

Like:

```html
    <table>
        <tr><th>name</th><th>proteins / 100g</th><th>carbohydrates / 100g</th></tr>
        <tr><td>potatoes</td><td>3g</td><td>20g</td></tr>
        <tr><td>chicken meat</td><td>20.04g</td><td>0.32g</td></tr>
        <tr><td>cucumber</td><td>0.7g</td><td>2.6g</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>tomatoes</td><td>0.98g</td><td>3.9g</td></tr>
    </table>
```

And i have a meal from these materails.

It has some ratio between materials, e.g:

---

Meat : potatoes : cucumber : tomatoes = 120 : 350 : 70 : 70

---

And i know a man with weight x and age a should eat:

175g of carbohydrates and 43g of proteins.

Now the algorithm should count how many of each material should be in the meal

The ratio is not so important - there can be a little deviation, more important is the final value - so i need weights of each material, so the meal will be as close as is possible to ideal values (above).

Thank you for any ideas or tips.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I have no idea if it is possible or how it is possible, maybe someone should help me with that algorithm

Comment: Are you looking for the algorithm in any specific language ?

Comment: Describing of the way will be engough, but it will be programmed in PHP